# Efficiently reorder a non-symmetrical, square matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix that is non-symmetrical, square (equal dimension), as follows:

```
m <- matrix(LETTERS[1:25], ncol=5, dimnames = list(1:5, 1:5))
diag(m) <- "-"
print(m, quote=FALSE)

  1 2 3 4 5
1 - F K P U
2 B - L Q V
3 C H - R W
4 D I N - X
5 E J O T -
```

I want to specify the rows/columns in a different order as follows:

```
new <- c(1, 5, 3, 2, 4)
```

The final unquoted output would look like this:

```
  1 5 3 2 4 
1 - U K F P
5 E - O J T
3 C W - H R
2 B V L - Q
4 D X N I -
```

How can I efficiently reorder a matrix like this that's generalizable to other similar non-symmetrical, square matrices?

The only way I could think to do this is by hand, but that's silly as I suspect there's probably a way to do this rather easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'm missing something here but can't you just reference in the indices?

```
> m[new,new]
  1   5   3   2   4  
1 "-" "U" "K" "F" "P"
5 "E" "-" "O" "J" "T"
3 "C" "W" "-" "H" "R"
2 "B" "V" "L" "-" "Q"
4 "D" "X" "N" "I" "-"
```

Comment: Nope, you're missing nothing, I was.  :-)  Easy solution that makes me feel like a doof.  Thanks.